# Simple Android authentication and requests after it

Tags: java, android, http, authentication, authorization

I'm implementing an android app and I'm having trouble understanding how I can implement a login feature (very simple, no encryption needed) and how it works after the user logs in

So, the first thing to do is make a Request, I send the login, and password,with an http POST method probably?
and the server replies with a token of some sort, correct?

Then I save that token, and what happens next? I have a bunch of pages I need to make GET requests on, but I also need to send the token someway, right?

How exactly can I make that?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it summed up I guess. Let the app send the credentials with a POST, the server checks if they are okay, then sends back a token (some random String maybe). When you make the GET requests after login, send the token with a custom HTTP header and let the server check it. The server has a list of valid tokens and checks if the received token is valid. If not, it responds with an error message, else it does what it's supposed to do. 
That's all very basic and not at all secure of course.

Edit: The GET request could be done like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("someUrl.com/rest");
get.setHeader("Authorization", "someTokenYouCreated");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

You'll find lot's of examples about calling a REST method. You'll have to look up how to handle that header on the server side, but that can't be too difficult either.

Comment: Thank you. About the final part, that's my main issue, do you have any pointers about how to create that GET request with a custom header in java?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's probably exactly what I'm looking for.